# How can I position SVG image center vertically and horizontally?

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I have check existing answers here. Unfortunately, it did not help at all. My question is particular to **SVG image**.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
  
  max-width: 1280px;

  width: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

        <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 807.2 400.42">
            <defs>
                <style>.cls-1 {
                    fill: #d1cfbf;
                }</style>
            </defs>
        </svg>
        </div>
```

I am trying to center the svg center horizontally and vertically. I have tried using Flexbox and absolute positioning. For some reasons, it does not align center.

PS: svg image is a dummy image but size is exact.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: Without the actual SVG we can't help. It's possible the viewbox is wrong. Your demo doesn't actually demonstrate the issue.

Comment: You are missing `justify-items:center` in body i think.. That should work if you are using flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with css and JavaScript.

The HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id="Layer_1"></svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

svg {
    position: relative;
}
```

The JavaScript.

```
function _id(e){
    return document.getElementById(e)
}

window.onload = function(){
    _id("Layer_1").style.marginTop = (window.innerHeight/2) - (_id("Layer_1").getBoundingClientRect().height/2) + "px";

    _id("Layer_1").style.marginLeft = (window.innerWidth/2) - (_id("Layer_1").getBoundingClientRect().width/2) + "px"
}
```

This should keep the svg element in the center no matter what the width or height is!